# Map objects from multiple properties Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper, .net-5

I would appreciate your inputs on accomplishing the mapping for the given scenario.

```
    class Section1
    {
        public string S1 { get; set; }
        public string S2 { get; set; }
        public string S3 { get; set; }
    }
    class Section2
    {
        public string S4 { get; set; }
        public string S5 { get; set; }
    }
    class Section3
    {
        public string S6 { get; set; }
        public string S7 { get; set; }
    }
    class SectionsInfo
    {
        public Section1 A { get; set; }
        public Section2 B { get; set; }
        public Section3 C { get; set; }
    }
    class SectionsTogetherInStraight
    {
        public string S1 { get; set; }
        public string S2 { get; set; }
        public string S3 { get; set; }
        public string S4 { get; set; }
        public string S5 { get; set; }
        public string S6 { get; set; }
        public string S7 { get; set; }           
    }
```

I have an object for class SectionsInfo and would like to configure AutoMapper for SectionsTogetherInStraight. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `MapFrom` or `ConstructUsing` methods to flatten the object.

More about it [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html)

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [Flattening](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html). With your naming convention, you will need to use the [`IncludeMembers`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers) method:

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    // Pull out the members of A, B, and C from SectionsInfo using IncludeMembers
    cfg.CreateMap<SectionsInfo, SectionsTogetherInStraight>()
        .IncludeMembers(s => s.A, s => s.B, s => s.C);

    // Map each section to the final destination (like normal).
    cfg.CreateMap<Section1, SectionsTogetherInStraight>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Section2, SectionsTogetherInStraight>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Section3, SectionsTogetherInStraight>();
});
```